# DropDownList FindByValue Problem

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, drop-down-menu

My first DDL works great:

```
        String BrandID = Request.QueryString["BrandID"];

        ddlChoseBrand.Items.FindByValue(BrandID).Selected = true;
```

My two other dosent work, how shall I write the code correct?

```
        CategoryAccess.GetDllInfo(id);

        String ModelID;
        String CategoryID;

        ddlChoseModel.Items.FindByValue(ModelID).Selected = true;
        ddlChoseCategory.Items.FindByValue(CategoryID).Selected = true;
```

In GetDllInfo I simply get witch one thats going to be selected. So the problem is that I dont know how to write the code correct.

Comment: It looks like your strings `ModelID` and `CategoryID` are empty strings `""`, and you are trying to select this value in your drop downs, is this what you intented?

Comment: No, I already have that value and I'm trying to get that value to be selected when the page loads, maybe something like this: String ModelID = CategoryAccess.GetDllInfo(id);

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem yesterday, It seems like .selected = true doesn't always work as We suppose to..

here is a little workaround you can use instead.

```
ListItem myitem = ddlChoseModel.Items.FindByValue(ModelID);
ddlChoseModel.SelectedValue = myitem.Value;
```

peerin mind that selectedValue is a Get property not Get/Set .. but It did worked great with me :D

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too with ddl, but mine was comparing with database.
find that .Trim() actually solves the problem.

EG:

```
ddlChoseCategory.Items.FindByValue(CategoryID.Trim()).Selected = true;
```

good luck for people who have the same problem as I am. :D